# How to permanently disable Storage device(SD card,Pen drive etc) from Android OS 4.0.4 Tablet?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I need to do changes in Android OS source code so that after compiling Source code i can ship OS images(system.img, boot.img,recovery.img) to the client.

I have deleted one folder `ROOT->kernel->drivers-> USB` but its not compiling in that case.

I don't want via command line because in that case that will be for specific computer, my requirement is to change in OS source code than compile and get OS images with these updates, so that i can distribute it and install it in  my h/w.

Can anyone tell me the correct file name where i need to change and if possible what to change as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Deleting? No No.. You just need to disable the configs,, deleting files is blunder....

Comment: yes, you are rite, deleting file is blunder... that's why it was not compiling and i got error. So please let me know , where i can find the usb config files. Where i need to change ? i don't know the files locations where to change.